# Magento EE 2.4.2-p1 Braintree Payment method error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, braintree, gene-braintree

We have upgraded our **Magento Enterprise Edition from 2.3.7 to 2.4.2-p1** and earlier we were using **gene/module-braintree** but after upgrade gene/module-braintree has been depreciated and now it is coming in **paypal/module-braintree-core**, and when we are trying to place order using production and sandbox credentials it is returning following error with both credentials:

**"message":"Sorry, but something went wrong","trace":"#0**

- Magento EE version:  2.4.2-p1
- PHP version: 7.4.2.0
- For credit card details please check the attached image.[image]

Anybody could help for the same issue,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you ever resolve this issue? Having the same problem myself except the error is "Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the store owner"

Comment: Yes Nick, I resolved this issue by creating new sandbox credentials for Braintree.